# Inserting data into cursor range and avoid the cursor reading it

Tags: sql, insert, cursor

I have an issue with a sql query.

For Eg: Consider Employee table,

```
Emp_No | Emp_Name

  1    |  AAA
...........
```

I am reading the table into a cursor.

```
Cursor c1 is select emp_no, emp_name from employee;
```

I am iterating the cursor and adding a record to the cursor another record at the end of it when it meets some cryteria. Is there any way to avoid the cursor to iterate through those newly inserted records?

Sorry for my English and, in case that this is already answered, sorry about it also.

Comment: Show us some more code!

Comment: If you will not use them, why do you add those records into the cursor? You can just use READ ONLY cursors and insert those new values into a table variable, etc then use from there after cursor execution finishes